# nodejs: inheriting EventEmitter

Tags: javascript, node.js, inheritance

I can't create a class inheriting from EventEmitter. The emit() function ends up being undefined. Here's a simplified extract of the problem:

```
var EventEmitter = require( 'events' );
var util = require( 'util' );
var zWave = require('./zWaveRequest.js');
var CronJobManager = require( 'cron-job-manager' );
var timespanToCron = require( './parseTime.js' ).timespanToCron;
var winston = require( './logger.js' );

const levelCronName = 'level';

var Switch = function (id, displayName, onTime, offTime) {
    var _nodeNum;
    var _nodeName;
    var _lastLevel = -1;
    var _levelPollInterval = config.levelPollInterval;
    var _levelTS = 0;
    var _cronMgr = new CronJobManager( );

    EventEmitter.call( this );

    var self = this;

    function initLevelJob() {
        // the log shows self.emit() doesn't exist (???)
        if( typeof self.emit === 'function' ) winston.info( 'initLevelJob(): self.emit() is defined' );
        else winston.info( 'initLevelJob(): self.emit() is NOT defined' );

        _cronMgr.add( levelCronName, timespanToCron( _levelPollInterval ), function() {
            self.getLevel();
        }, 
        {
            start: true,
        } );
    }

    this.getLevel = function() {
        zWave.curLevel( _nodeNum )
        .then( function( value ) {
            _lastLevel = value;
            _levelTS = Date.now( );

            // this next call always fails with an 'emit is not a function' error
            self.emit( 'level', self.lastLevel, self.lastLevelTS );
        } );
    }

    Object.defineProperties(this, {
        nodeNumber: {
            get: function() { return _nodeNum; },
            set: function( val ) {
                _nodeNum = val;
                initLevelJob( );
            },
        },

        levelPollInterval: {
            get: function() { return _levelPollInterval; },
            set: function( val ) {
                _levelPollInterval = val;
                initLevelJob( );
            }
        },
}

util.inherits( Switch, EventEmitter );

module.exports = Switch;
```

The overall idea here is that a cronjob gets set up to ping another server for information (that's the call to zWave). The cronjob callback updates some internal variables and then emits an event.

But self.emit() is undefined, even though I thought I was following the examples of how to inherit from EventEmitter.

**Calling Code**

From the point of view of how I'm trying to use emit() right now, nothing happens outside of a Switch object. In other words, I don't have any event listeners tied into Switch yet.

Here's how I am creating instances of Switch (SunsetSwitch is derived from Switch):

```
function createSwitch( switchFile ) {
    var raw = JSON.parse( fs.readFileSync( switchFile ) );
    var retVal;

    if( typeof raw.onTime === 'undefined' ) {
        // sunset switch
        retVal = new SunsetSwitch( );

        if( config.forceImmediateOn ) {
            var now = new Date( );

            var sunset = sunCalc.getTimes( now, config.latitude, config.longitude ).sunset;
            retVal.onOffset = Math.ceil( ( now - sunset ) / 60000 ) - 5;

            var turnOff = new Date( now );
            turnOff.setMinutes( now.getMinutes( ) + config.testMode.duration.totalMinutes() );
            retVal.offTime = turnOff;

            retVal.basedOnSunrise = raw.basedOnSunrise;
        }
        else {
            retVal.onOffset = raw.onOffset;
            retVal.offTime = raw.offTime;
            retVal.basedOnSunrise = raw.basedOnSunrise;
        }
    }
    else {
        // regular switch
        retVal = new Switch( );

        retVal.offTime = raw.offTime;
        retVal.onTime = raw.onTime;
    }

    if( config.forceImmediateOn ) retVal.ignoreInitialOff = false;
    else {
        if( typeof raw.ignoreInitial != 'boolean' ) retVal.ignoreInitialOff = true;
        else retVal.ignoreInitialOff = raw.ignoreInitialOff;
    }

    retVal.displayName = raw.displayName;
    retVal.nodeName = raw.nodeName;
    retVal.nodeNumber = raw.nodeNumber;

    return retVal;
}
```

createSwitch() is called from a filesystem loop that reads a bunch of json files:

```
fs.readdirSync('./switches')
.filter(function (file) {
    return file.substr(-5) === '.json';
})
.forEach(function (file) {
    switches.push(createSwitch('./switches/' + file));
});
```

Here's the error message I'm currently getting:

> Unhandled rejection TypeError: self.emit is not a function
>       at /home/mark/XmasLights/switch.js:65:18
>       at tryCatcher (/home/mark/XmasLights/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:11:23)
>       at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/home/mark/XmasLights/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:488:31)
>       at Promise._settlePromise (/home/mark/XmasLights/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:545:18)
>       at Promise._settlePromise0 (/home/mark/XmasLights/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:590:10)
>       at Promise._settlePromises (/home/mark/XmasLights/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:673:18)
>       at Async._drainQueue (/home/mark/XmasLights/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:125:16)
>       at Async._drainQueues (/home/mark/XmasLights/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:135:10)
>       at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (/home/mark/XmasLights/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:16:14)
>       at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:383:17)

Here is an extract of how a SunsetSwitch is defined:

```
var Switch = require('./switch.js');

var SunsetSwitch = function (id, displayName, onOffset, offTime) {
    Switch.call(this, id, displayName, null, offTime);
}

module.exports = SunsetSwitch;
```

Comment: Is `this.emit` defined inside the constructor?

Comment: What version of node are you using?

Comment: Also, are you using `new Switch()` or just `Switch()` when instantiating?

Comment: I'm using v5.1.0. I'm creating instances via new Switch(),

Comment: Your issue likely has with how you' re using the instantiated object so we will need to see that code.  The subclassing itself (that you have shown) looks fine.

Comment: posted a bunch of additional info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanx to everyone who responded, and particularly to jfriend00, who put me on the trail to the solution.

The problem stemmed from something I didn't do in defining SunsetSwitch, which is derived from Switch.

I neglected to include this line in the module file for SunsetSwitch:

```
util.inherits( SunsetSwitch, Switch );
```

Based on my limited understanding of javascript, that omission prevented the prototype from Switch from being propagated to SunsetSwitch.

I need to remember that defining an inheritance tree in javascript isn't as simple as it is in, for example, C#, where I have most of my experience. You have to both set the properties -- Switch.call(this, id, displayName, null, offTime) -- and copy the prototypes -- util.inherits( SunsetSwitch, Switch ).